# Mocking a class in typescript with jest

Tags: class, typescript, mocking, jestjs

I am trying to unit test (with Jest) my handler module that makes use of a summary class.

My original summary class looks like:

```
import DynamoDBClient from './ddbClient/DynamoDBClient'
import { DynamoDB } from 'aws-sdk'
import { iSummaryReader, iObsSummariesAttributes } from './Summary.d'
import { JSONAPIResource } from '../JSONAPIResponse'

export default class Summary {
  reader: iSummaryReader

  constructor(reader: iSummaryReader) {
    this.reader = reader
  }


  getSummary = async (keyName: string, keyValue: string): Promise<JSONAPIResource<iObsSummariesAttributes>> => {
    return new Promise<JSONAPIResource<iObsSummariesAttributes>>((resolve, reject) => {
      const gettingItem = this.reader.getItem(keyName, keyValue)
      console.log(gettingItem)
      gettingItem.then((resp) => {
        resolve(resp)
      }).catch((err: Error) => {
        reject(err.message)
      })
    })
  }
}
```

In my handler module I import with `import Summary from './lib/Summary'`
(Note: same line is used in `handler.test.ts`

Inside the handler function

```
try {
  const dynamodbObj: iSummaryReader = new DynamoDBClient(documentClient, someTable)
  const summary = new Summary(dynamodbObj)
  const data: JSONAPIResource<iObsSummariesAttributes> = await summary.getSummary('id', someID)
}
```

My results depend on my approach if try an automatic mock

```
jest.mock('./lib/Summary', () =>
{
  return {
    getSummary: jest.fn()
  }
})
```

I get the error

> TypeError: Summary_1.default is not a constructor

If I create a manual mock under `lib/__mocks__/Summary.ts` with `jest.mock('./lib/Summary')` it does work until I get the point

```
expect(Summary).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
```

Where it complains about me not being able to do this on summary.  I also am unable to access my method to test that they are being called this way.

Note: My hanlder is for a lambda function so I am unable to inject the class that way where I have successfully tested that I can mock an injected class.

EDIT

The tsconfig.json is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "outDir": "./build",
    "declaration": false,
    "target": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015.promise",
      "es2017.object",
      "es2016"
    ],
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
}
```

Comment: It must be something to do with the tsconfig.json file. Can you post the config setings in it, its location?

Comment: Don't you need to mock the export named `default` when mocking a module? I don't know as I haven't used jest but I would imagine it's entirely ambiguous if you don't, and the framework is probably assuming that you're trying to mock the module namespace object because that's the only non ambiguous interpretation

Comment: @AluanHaddad I was closely following the example provided in the jest documentation which does it that way https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/es6-class-mocks.html, I am assuming the issue was do with the way typescript does it's imports.

Comment: @user3559247 make sure you use TypeScript's `--esModuleInterop` flag and the latest language version. TypeScript now provides import interop in the standard way, behavior being similar to Babel and SystemJS. However, given that what you have is a `default` anyway it shouldn't make a difference, but using those settings will allow you to write correct and standards compliant code without relying on additional transpiler and loaders that may not be as easily  portable between testing environments and browsers

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why this was failing, but I the following steps seem to work to fix it.

1. Change the class export from default

From

```
`export default class Summary {`
```

to

```
`class summary`
```

+ `export = summary` at the end

2. Use import = require to import it.

   `import Summary = require('./lib/Summary')`

Those two changes allowed it to find the jest.mock.